# Class versions V1_5 or less must use F_NEW frames

Tags: java

What are the possibilities that a Java function would return this `Class versions V1_5 or less must use F_NEW frames.`? I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my web application, but accessing resources returns that text.

The Java version installed in my server is

```
~# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.48.0.53-CA-linux64) (build 1.8.0_265-b11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.48.0.53-CA-linux64) (build 25.265-b11, mixed mode)
```

And my web application POM configuration have

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it causing your code to fail or just adding warnings to the logs? Are you running in eclipse when it happens? If so this might be relevant to you. I have the same warning many times on tomcat startup from eclipse but found it to be harmless.

Depending on a debug setting, eclipse makes a byte-code change when you launch from the IDE. If it is enabled then the F_NEW frames warnings are reported when tomcat is started. The Eclipse setting is "Use advanced source lookup (JRE 1.5 and higher)" in Preferences -> Java -> Debug. If I disable it then the warnings stop. The feature is documented [here](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/jdt.php)